# Jquery scroll to bottom syntax

Tags: jquery

I'm a new Jquery programmer and came across the two lines of code in stackoverflow that do exactly what I want (i.e. scroll to the bottom of my div called textelement).  The syntax of these lines, however, is unfamiliar to me.  I've searched for an explanation of how $container is used here and what the[0] means but can't find an answer.  Any small hints welcome.  I promise I'll ask more sophisticated questions as I learn the language.

```
$container = $('#textelement');
$container[0].scrollTop = $container[0].scrollHeight;
```

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: The `[0]` refers to the [DOM element](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/), in native JS, that is part of the jQuery object. You can use native JS methods and functions on this object, attach event handlers or set/fetch properties — https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `$container` is just a variable referencing the set of all objects matching the selector `$('...')`. The return is basically an array of all elements matching the selector. Specifically, the selector with `#` means that it gets all elements with "id" attribute of "textelement", which by definition of being an id should mean you only get 1 element back. The `$container[0]` means you get the first element of the array back. It's not really the best way to do this since if there are no matches, you have a javascript error. Since you are querying by id, you don't really need to have a specific element, but if you are concerned for some scenario, you can just call `$container.first()`.

The rest of the code is just a technique for setting the scroll position to scroll to your element.

For more details on how to build selectors:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Jason,  thank you so much.  I'm looking forward to using JQuery and your answer is just what I needed.  So nice to volunteer your time to answer the post.